# Netcdf java library for reading HDf5 error

Tags: java, hdf5, netcdf

I am a newbie to netcdf library and i am currently using it to read the metadata from a hdf5 file in java. After reading, I thought that netcdf is a decent enough library for my use, so using it.

however in the first step when i try to read the file it throws an error

```
LOGGER.debug("Inside Try");
//InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(h5File);
                //parser.parse(fileStream, handler, metadata);

  LOGGER.debug("path is :"+ h5File.getPath());
   NetcdfFile hf5File = NetcdfFile.open(h5File.getPath());



    LOGGER.debug("Got NetCdFile");
```

I am assuming the problem occurs when i try to open it , as it says :

> Inside Try
>   13:42:04.393 [main] DEBUG e.k.n.c.m.e.HDF5MetadataExtractor - path is :/var/www/webdav/admin/1151/data/XXXX.h5
>   13:42:04.495 [main] DEBUG ucar.nc2.NetcdfFile - Using IOSP ucar.nc2.iosp.hdf5.H5iosp
>   13:42:04.544 [main] ERROR ucar.nc2.iosp.hdf5.H5header - shape[0]=0 must be > 0

My Hd5f is a 2 dimensional array of integers, I am not interested in the array as such but with the metadata group associated with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetCDF-4 creates HDF5 files, it's true.  The HDF5 library can read the HDF5-formatted files produced by NetCDF-4, but NetCDF-4 cannot read arbitrary HDF5 files.

Either you have found a bug in Netcdf-Java, or you have an odd HDF5 file. Have you confirmed this file is not corrupted in some way?  Things i would try:
- use the C utility 'ncdump -h' to inspect the header
- use the HDF5 C utility 'h5dump -H' to inspect the file via HDF5

If both of those commands give sensible output, then the issue might rest with netcdf-java.

Comment: thank you i guess i missed this vital part that the NetCDF lib should be used to create HDf5 . i am not sure if this was done in my case when producing the HDf5 . So yes happy to accept this answer. I am going to use the HDF5 java lib. Any pointers if i need to read custom metadata folder in HDf5 files , if JHi5 library is good enough or Java HDf5 object package ?

Comment: I don't have any first-hand experience with the java bindings to any of these libraries, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Netcdf-Java is a pure Java implementation that can *read* most HDF5 files, details here: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/CDM/index.html#HDF5

If you find a failure, submit a bug report (and the file!) to netcdf-java@unidata.ucar.edu (must sign up here: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/index.html#mailinglists). But first make sure you have tried the latest version (currently 4.6.3).

Netcdf-Java can *write* netCDF-4 files (which are HDF5 files) through a JNI interface to the netcdf-4 C library. HDF5 java libraries are also JNI interfaces, except directly to the HDF5 C library. HDF5 java libraries cannot write netCDF4 files (unless you *really* know what you are doing) because HDF5 does not implement shared dimensions, which are essential to the netCDF data model.

For earth science, this leads to the argument (disclaimer: by me) that you should write netCDF-4, not directly HDF5, details here: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/en/entry/dimensions_scales.

Well, thats probably more information than you wanted ;^)